# Find coordinates of high frequency centers after plotting fftshifted image with Python

Tags: image-processing, scipy, fft, python-3.7

I am trying to write a code to detect Moire Patterns in images. I am quite new to image processing in Python, so please excuse me if the solution is trivial.

My approach is, to use the scipy fftshift function to distinguish between Moire and non Moire images (see below). Moire images have several high frequency centers, whereas normal images only have one center.

I would like to get the coordinates of these "centers", but I don't know how to do it exactly.
I am happy about every suggestion!

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import *
import imageio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

moire = imageio.imread(imgpath1)
nonMoire = imageio.imread(imgpath2)

moire = np.dot(moire[...,:3], [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140])
nonMoire = np.dot(nonMoire[...,:3], [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140])

noisy_gray_fft = fft2(moire)
orig_gray_fft = fft2(nonMoire)

orig_gray_fft_shift = fftshift(orig_gray_fft)
noisy_gray_fft_shift = fftshift(noisy_gray_fft)

plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(np.abs(noisy_gray_fft_shift), cmap='gray', norm=LogNorm(vmin=5))
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(np.abs(orig_gray_fft_shift), cmap='gray', norm=LogNorm(vmin=5))
```

Non Moire original:
[image: Original non Moire]

Moire original:
[image: Original Moire]

After FFT:
[image: After FFT]

Comment: You can try use scipy.signal.find_peaks() function.

Comment: @Riprip will you please post the photos used as Moire, non-Moire example photos, [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can run the code directly.

Comment: @BelalHomaidan I edited my post accordingly

Comment: @Riprip thanks for your rapid response, but I mean the input photos in their raw format '.png or .jpg  etc...', not the output of the python code or Matplotlib figure.

Comment: @BelalHomaidan Sorry I misunderstood. Is this alright?

Comment: @Riprip yes thanks.

Comment: @BelalHomaidan edited it once again

Comment: @Riprip running your code on your images I have got different [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vl70R.jpg) in the frequency domain, I couldn't get many centres as you have got here! can you please run this code on these images and confirm if the results will be the same as the figure you have posted?

Comment: @BelalHomaidan that is strange. I edited my post and reuploaded these images again, for me they are working. Could you try it again?

Comment: @Riprip now after I downloaded the new photo the results are identical.